# Look for a drop-in image resize/crop view controller

Tags: ios, ipad

I am looking for a third-party view controller that can be easily used to resize/crop UIImage provided. I am using it for profile avatar editing before upload.

Aviary's photo editor is awesome (https://github.com/AviaryInc/Mobile-Feather-SDK-for-iOS), but it has a 28MB libAviarySDK.a file, which doesn't make sense as it also contains a AviarySDKResources.bundle file.

Can anyone recommend some good alternatives?

Comment: One such popular library is NYXImagesKit: https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesKit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/ardalahmet/SSPhotoCropperViewController

https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGImageUtilities