# iOS - Best way to select an area of an image

Tags: iphone, ios, image

i am looking for the best way to select an area of an image.
In fact i want to load some jpg, and let the user scale or move it and get the coordinates on the image of a predrawn square at the center of the image.
What is the best way to do that ? is there a github library someone knows ? 
Thanks in advance
bye

Comment: Drop-in replacements:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968845/look-for-a-drop-in-image-resize-crop-view-controller

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951268/image-crop-in-ios-using-bjimagecropper

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use `UIImagePickerController` class.

You invoque it this way:

```
-(void) choosePhotoFromLibrary{

    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    // Shows the controls for moving & scaling pictures 
    // To instead hide the controls, use NO.
    cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;
    cameraUI.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

And then get the edited image this way:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


    UIImage * original = info[@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];
    //Do whatever you want with the image

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```